# Cron's don't run at all - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, cron

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and, since then, the cron jobs don't work.

For both root and normal users cron scripts fail to run. Just for testing I create the following in the root crontab

```
* * * * * env > /home/user/.logs/env.log
```

As I understand, this should just keep longing the environment info to the `env.log` but nothing happens.

I also turned on logging and got this in `/var/cron.log`:

```
Mar 30 19:46:01 w2 CRON[5681]: Error in service module
Mar 30 19:46:01 w2 CRON[5681]: Error in service module
Mar 30 19:47:01 w2 CRON[5695]: Error in service module
Mar 30 19:47:01 w2 CRON[5695]: Error in service module
```

I've tried googling for this, but didn't come up with anything. If anyone has any idea how to fix this please let me know.

Comment: Does `systemctl status cron.service` provide any further information?

Comment: Mar 31 06:25:01 w2.fiendishplan.com CRON[17356]: pam_limits(cron:session): error parsing the configuration file: '/etc/security/limits.conf'
and thanks I'll look into this

Comment: Interesting - never seen that before. The default limits.conf file is full of comments (indicating default values) so a good start might be to examine any non-comment lines ex. `grep -v '^[ \t]*#' /etc/security/limits.conf | cat -A`

Comment: Thanks.  In case anyone runs into the same problem the /etc/security directory was completely missing from the server.  I copied the directory from a know good server and cron worked again.

Comment: Please consider writing that up as an answer. You might also have considered finding all the packages that own files in /etc/security (using `dpkg -S /etc/security/` for example) and re-installing them.